# How to fetch N requests sequentially

Tags: javascript, fetch

Let's say I request a url, which returns the max number of pages, ie 5. I then need to request page 2, 3, 4 and 5.

However, as to not get blocked, these can't be done all at the same time but rather sequentially so `Promise.all()` is not gonna work (if I understand it correctly).

If I knew how many pages I have to get beforehand, I could just chain `.then`s, but I only get the info after the first request.

Also the data from all the requests have to be gathered, processed and passed to another function.

I suspect it will have something to do with promises? But how to chain those properly is beyond me.

Comment: Worst and easiest way - run loop and write async await store in an array types with flags ( if needed )

Comment: Perhaps read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: _"However, as to not get blocked..."_ what do you mean by that?  Are you talking about getting banned form a website because you're making too many requests?  (Or maybe just getting rate-limited?)  Or are you talking about avoiding having to wait for a result?  I'm not sure why you say "these can't be done all at the same time".

Comment: It sounds like you should `await` the first request and then run the n page requests in parallel with `Promise.all` but you didn't post any code, so hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it manually a tool like [`p-limit`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-limit#readme)

Example:

```
import pLimit from 'p-limit';

const limit = pLimit(1);

async function getData(x: number) {
  // do whatever you neeed aasynchronously here
  return x;
}

async function otherFunction() {
  // some input parameters for the async getData function:
  const input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

  // set concurrency limit to 5:
  const limit = pLimit(5);

  // run Promite.all on the closures processed by your `limit`
  return Promise.all(input.map(e => limit(() => getData(e))));
}
```

Comment: @PeterB good point, I removed the links and wrote my own example of one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch requests sequentially by defining `Promise.resolve()`, and chaining it every iteration.

```js
let urls = [];
Array(21).fill('').forEach((_,i)=>{
  urls.push('https://dummyjson.com/carts/'+(i+1));
});

let promise = Promise.resolve();
console.time('time execution');
urls.forEach((url,i) => {
  promise = promise.then(() => 
    fetch(url)
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(r => console.log(r))
    .catch(e => console.error(e))
    .finally(() => {
      if(i === urls.length - 1) console.timeEnd('time execution');
    }) 
  );
});
```

---

**Another way: Use async-await**

```js
let urls = [];
Array(21).fill('').forEach((_,i)=>{
  urls.push('https://dummyjson.com/carts/'+(i+1));
});

(async () => {
  console.time('time execution')
  for(let [i,url] of urls.entries()) {
    console.log(await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fetch(url)
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(r => resolve(r))
      .catch(e => reject(e))
      .finally(() => {
        if(i === urls.length - 1) console.timeEnd('time execution');
      });
    }));
  }
})();
```